# Update column from another table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables(**violator and officer)** and both of them have column name **reference**, now what I want to do is whenever I add a new value to the **violator** table, the value of its **reference** should be equal to the value of **reference** on **officer** table. I am new to programming but how can I achieve that? I couldn't quite understand the notes I can find on the internet. This is how I add values to the **violator** table:

**php**

```
<?php
$user_name = "Demo";
$password = "Demopass";
$server = "localhost";
$db_name = "TMTRO";

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password, $db_name);
if ($con) {

    $Name = $_POST['name'];
    $LName = $_POST['lname'];
    $LNumber = $_POST['lnumber'];
    $Violation = $_POST['violation'];
    $Aplace = $_POST['aplace'];
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $PNumber = $_POST['pnumber'];
    $OName = $_POST['oname'];
    $RNumber = $_POST['rnumber'];
    $DTime = $_POST['dtime'];
    $query = "insert into violators (name,lname,lnumber,violation,aplace,address,pnumber,oname,reference,datetime) values ('" . $Name . "','" . $LName . "','" . $LNumber . "','" . $Violation . "','" . $Aplace . "','" . $Address . "','" . $PNumber . "','" . $OName . "','" . $RNumber . "','" . $DTime . "');";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ($result) {

        $status = 'OK';


    } else {
        $status = 'FAILED';
    }

} else {
    $status = 'FAILED';
}

echo json_encode(array("response" => $status));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: please,**never** use direct assignment of `$_POST` values (this is 100% SQL-injection), sanitize and validate first, please read [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595) at least

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.